# UFT Spy object doesn't capture web objects

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, uft14, uft-api

i'm facing the current problem by using UFT One version 15.0 build 1116: i cannot capture any element on the web because the object spy identifies everithing as a "WinObject: CHrome Legacy Window".
What i've tried:

- reinstall the uft agent extension for chrome giving all the permissions
- create another solution/test
- disabled all the chrome extensions except the uft
- restart pc

Here the problem:
[image]

here the config of the chrome extension:
[image]

The same issue if i try to catch the objects in edge.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION: the resolution of the screen pc must be at 100%, mine was 125%. Changing this and reeboting the pc has worked, hope this will help somebody else

Answer (score 1):

You should update to a more current UFT version.

And if you are in a secure environment, you must make sure the UFT browser extension is not blacklisted/is whitelisted (see documentation for lots and lots of details).

Also, you should start the browser after (or via) UFT if you haven't.

You will probably not solve this with UFT 15 and current Chromium-based browsers (Chrome and Chromium Edge).

Comment: SOLUTION: after tried a lot of stuff, the problem was the resolution of the pc that was on 125%. Changing it to 100% and restarting the pc has made the magic. Cannot understand why, but that has worked.

Comment: Known issue/limitation. But thanks for communicating the solution here!